# Where can I host assets for free?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, assets

I have a photo-gallery in Rails and the assets-images take around 1Gb of space. 
Since I just created the website, I want to host them somewhere outside of the project for free as a **temporary** solution and for other reasons as well.

Where can I host them? Dropbox comes to mind but as far as I know, that won't work.

Comment: what are you using to host the rails app?  Dropbox won't work.

Comment: I know the three cents per month is kinda steep, but have you considered https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/?

Comment: @BradWerth, does this price remain the same for 1Gb storage regardless the website traffic? Meaning, no matter how many visitors I have, I'll only pay $0.3 per month for 1Gb of the images?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 has a free tier that offers 5gb of space for free for a year, and then charges a small fee after that.

Comment: Downvoting for answering off-topic question instead of VTC.

Comment: @BradWerth, who do you address that to? It's not me who did it.